# A bit of a complexity in Using the factory design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

As it is said "if we have a super class and n sub-classes, and based on data provided, we have to return the object of one of the sub-classes, we use a factory pattern"

**Situation:**
I have 20 clients, more can be added with time. Each will provide a file from which data would be extracted and inserted into the db. Every client has his own style of mainting the file i.e. data fields would be at different places.

**Solution:**
For this I think I will have to use factory design pattern, I create 20 classes and every class has its own implementation of every field, like how and from which place in file it has to extract it. As new clients are added, I just create a new class and I am done, no other changes are required.

**Am I correct till here?**

**Complexity:**
Now the problem is that the files that clients' provide, can be in either of the 4 formats (PDF, XLS(X), HTML, TXT). THe engine that extracts text from these formats has to be static, like I use pdftoXML to extract PDF to XML etc. If I dont create a seperate engine class that just converts the PDF to XML then I would have to re-write the functionality of PDF text extraction in every client's class that provides file in PDF. The same is the case with excel extraction engine.

**Question:**
How should I encorporate these engines in factory pattern? Should the engines classes be static and the sub class that has to deal with pdf for example, calls the pdf class' extract method to get the reqtuired data or what?

Hope I made myself clear, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use of Factory Method, but don't try to use the client class hierarchy to model the extraction algorithms as well. In terms of patterns, you could use Strategy to dynamically configure a client object with the right kind of extraction algorithm.

Comment: "client class hierarchy to model the extraction algorithms as well" sorry dint get this?

Comment: If several clients use the same extraction algorithm, don't try to put the shared extraction algorithm into a common superclass. Find another way of sharing it, perhaps by using the Strategy pattern.

Comment: Like the idea of strategy in this case, think i should go for this, but why not use a common superclass any known issues in that?

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) two things going on here.

1. Extracting text from a range of file formats
2. Parsing this text according to client specific rules.

I would separate these functions completely. Perhaps even have two factories, one for text extraction and one for parsing. The client specific code that does the parsing, does not need to know that the text came from a PDF, CSV, or was piped in over http or whatever. It merely needs to know about parsing text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think a better idea, but to link these two? If I create two factories, does the first factory which does the parsing calls the text extraction factory or what?

Answer (score 1):

To start with, a few questions.  These may change the suggested solution:

1. Does each of the 20 clients have a single FileFormat?
2. What is common (behavior/methods) between the subclasses?
3. Is there ever a chance that a subclass might change such that is utilizes a different FileFormat?

In the simplest solution where subclasses do not need to switch file types, Seems like right now you could have an abstract ContentProvider which is subclassed by a set of abstract classes PdfProvider, XlsProvider, HtmlProvider, and TxtProvider.  This middle layer of classes implement the file-format specific functionality.  Then your 20 "client" classes inherit from the appropriate FileFormat-specific base.

Comment: 1. no, they can have either a PDF/excel or html file
2. the common behaviour is the common filds like every file will have a date, customer no, product no. etc.
3. yes there is a slight chance of it, but we wouldnt like to cater that